C++ app using Xlib exits with non zero return value
When my X11 window gets a DestroyNotify event, I would like to close my app, however my process exits with 1 instead of 0. When I run it in debug mode, I get the following error:
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Reproduction code:
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main()
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window window;

    XVisualInfo visual_info;
    long visual_mask = VisualScreenMask;
    int number_of_visuals;
    XVisualInfo v_info_template = {};
    v_info_template.screen = DefaultScreen(display);
    XVisualInfo *vi_list = XGetVisualInfo(display, visual_mask, &v_info_template, &number_of_visuals);
    visual_info = vi_list[0];
    XFree(vi_list);
    Colormap colormap = XCreateColormap(display, RootWindow(display, visual_info.screen), visual_info.visual, AllocNone);
    XSetWindowAttributes window_attributes = {};
    window_attributes.colormap = colormap;
    window_attributes.background_pixel = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    window_attributes.border_pixel = 0;
    window_attributes.event_mask = KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | StructureNotifyMask | ExposureMask;
    unsigned long value_mask = CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask;

    window = XCreateWindow(display, RootWindow(display, visual_info.screen), 100, 100, 500, 500, 0, visual_info.depth, InputOutput, visual_info.visual, value_mask, &window_attributes);

    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XSync(display, False);

    XEvent* event = nullptr;
    while(!event || event->type != DestroyNotify) {
        XCheckWindowEvent(display, window, VisibilityChangeMask, event);
    }

    XUnmapWindow(display, window);
    XDestroyWindow(display, window);
    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}


while(!event || event->type == DestroyNotify) looks odd.  Shouldn't it be while(!event || event->type != DestroyNotify) -- or have I misunderstood?

@G.M. thank you, indeed, I fixed it. The issue is still there though.

You should check How do I gracefully exit an X11 event loop?. The issue is that you are using the [X] button to close the app.  That's not, strictly speaking, an X11 component.  That's part of the window manager, which sends you a window message and then forcefully kills the app.  X11 is a mess, which is why there are so many higher level libraries to hide it from you.

Thank you @TimRoberts, it looks promising :)
